# Typcasting from void* to int and vice versa

Tags: c, casting, pthreads

I've been working on a threads lately and I have a question here. Here is a code snippet I have:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, hello, (void *) i);
```

And in the thread hello, I print the value i that I have passed on from the above.

```
void *hello(void *n)
{ 
   printf( " %d " , n);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The question is:
While there is a need for me to typecast i to (void *), why can I succesfully print out the i without having to recast it back to int?

Comment: Don't do things like that, the pthread interface is meant to receive a pointer to data and not an integer. That is prints well is pure coincidence. You are probably on a 32 bit machine where pointers and `int` have the same width.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably on a 32 bit machine where pointers and `int` have the same width. So it is pure coincidence that this prints well.

This is really bad coding style, buys you a lot of trouble if you want to port your code, but gives you no gain at all. Just don't.